# Dom Parse multiple tables

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to access information from both the first and second table on a website. Using the below code I am only able to access the first table. What syntax to I use to get to the second  or the nth table?

```
$url = "http://iditarod.com/race/2014/";

//new dom object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

//load the html
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

//discard white space 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

//the table by its tag name
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

//get all rows from the table
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the second table, use `item(1)`. To get the *nth* table, use *n - 1*.

What [`getElementsByTagName('table')`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) returns is a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) which contains all the [elements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) named "table" in the document. The DOMNodeList method [`item()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) returns a [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) from that list at the given index, with the item index starting at 0.

So to get all the rows from the second table:

```
$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```